# Angular 2+ FCM getToken() does not return anything

Tags: angular, push, message

I am writing FCM with Chrome.

The code below works fine.

```
this.messaging.requestPermission()
        .then(() => { ... })
```

But after I got permission, when I want to get token, there is nothing returned from getToken(). It does not call .then() or even .catch().

```
this.messaging.getToken()
        .then( t => console.log(t) )
        .catch( e => console.error(e) );
```

Please help me.

Comment: It was my mistake. I unregistered the service worker and tried again. it is working.

Comment: If you unregister the service worker, then how come it is working as without the service worker it wont work. Please explain